# GWT RequestFactory: How can I get a persistent id from stableId()?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I use `Long` ids in my entities, not only to store them in the datastore, but to reference other entities.  Now, I'm using RequestFactory to create() objects on the client and persist them, but I need a way to figure out what id the server has generated.

Here's one way I've figured out that requires two trips:

```
final OrganizationProxy proxy = context.create(OrganizationProxy.class);
context.persist().using(proxy).fire(new Receiver<Void>(){

    public void onSuccess(Void response)
    {
        requestFactory.find(proxy.stableId()).fire(new Receiver<OrganizationProxy>()
        {
            public void onSuccess(OrganizationProxy response)
            {
                //hey, now response has the server-generated id in it, along with any other values the server populated
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But it seems like there *must* be a way to get the persistent id without the second trip.  It seems like requestFactory.find() would need the persistent id to work at all in the first place.

How can I get at the persistent id without a second request to the server?

***=======Update=======***

It finally occurred to me (after tbroyer [told me](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/4a028dc1f536488f/ad0bc3ce9460b572?lnk=gst&q=stableId#ad0bc3ce9460b572) ;)) that I could return the `Long` id from the persist() method in the RequestContext.  This doesn't retrieve the persistent id from the `EntityProxyId`, but it does get me the persistent id of a new object in a single request.

I'll leave this question open - I am still interested in getting the persistent id out of an EntityProxyId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class implementing an `EntityProxyId` is `SimpleEntityProxyId`. This class has a method `getServerId()`, which will return the id. So by checking with `instanceof` you can then call the method. (Actually `RequestFactory.getHistoryToken()` doesn't even check, but simply casts to this class).

Now the bad news: it's encoded and the base class for `SimpleEntityProxyId`, which is `SimpleProxyId` and contains the method `getServerId()`, specifically states:

> The encodedAddress is totally opaque to the client. It's probably a base64-encoded string, but it could be digits of pi. Any code that does anything other than send the contents of this field back to the server is wrong.

(Where the field `encodedAddress` contains the server id.)

Answer (score 9):

You can get a String representation of an EntityProxyId by calling [`RequestFactory.getHistoryToken()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/RequestFactory.html#getHistoryToken%28com.google.gwt.requestfactory.shared.EntityProxyId%29).  This can be converted back to an `EntityProxyId` by calling [`RequestFactory.getProxyId()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/RequestFactory.html#getProxyId%28java.lang.String%29).

In RequestFactory parlance, the id of a newly-created entity is "ephemeral."  An ephemeral id is only valid within the instance of the `RequestFactory` that created the `RequestContext` used to create the `EntityProxy`.  When the `RequestContext` is fired and all method invocations have been processed by the server, the `SimpleRequestProcessor` will check the payload's ephemeral objects and if they have been persisted, the resulting payload will update the client's state with the value returned from the `getId()` method.

The object identity and equality of an `EntityProxyId` won`t change when it switches from the ephemeral to persistent state, but its associated history token will change:

```
OrganizationProxy proxy = context.create(OrganizationProxy.class);
final EntityProxyId<?> id = proxy.stable();
String ephemeralString = factory.getHistoryToken(id);
context.persist().using(proxy).fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
  public void onSuccess(Void response) {
    String persistedString = factory.getHistoryToken(id);
    assert !ephemeralString.equals(persistedString);
    assert factory.getProxyId(ephemeral) == factory.getProxyId(persistedString);

    MyRequestFactory otherFactory = GWT.create(MyRequestFactory.class);
    assert factory.getProxyId(ephemeral) != otherFactory.getProxyId(ephemeral);
    // Throws IllegalArgumentException
    otherFactory.find(otherFactory.getProxyId(ephemeral));
  }
});
```

In the above demo, once you have `persistedString`, you can stash the value in a cookie or some other client-side persistence mechanism and re-create the id later to be used with a call to `RequestFactory.find()`.  The second and third assertions demonstrate the "scope" of an ephemeral id.  The ephemeral and persisted forms can be used interchangeably with the `RequestFactory` that created the object.  If an ephemeral id is used with a newly-created instance of a `RequestFactory` (which would happen if an ephemeral id were bookmarked as a `History` token), you'll get an `EntityProxyId`, but it can't really be used for any useful purpose.

Comment: Thanks - it's really helpful to have a list of specific assertions like this.

Answer (score 1):

I just declared the getId() method in my Proxy interface and it seems to work. Is there any problem with this approach?