# How to Obtain Entity Identifiers in GWT?

Tags: gwt, entity, requestfactory

When creating a new entity (in relational database terms a new row in a table) in a GWT application I need to provide a unique identifier for the new entity, and that identifier needs to be unique across all concurrent users of the system. In light of this I can't generate the new identifier on the client side ... I need to request it from the server. I'm using Request Factory for the application, and so I don't typically use GWT RPC to communicate with the server, but I think it may be the best way to request a unique identifier in this case. What is the best way to obtain a unique identifier? And if there are default values for some of the fields (columns) in a new entity where would you obtain those values? Would you get them from the server? Or embed them in the client code?

Comment: Can you return the id of new entity from the RF call that creates it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058940/gwt-requestfactory-how-can-i-get-a-persistent-id-from-stableid

Comment: Currently I don't fire a request context for inserting a new entity until the user has finished editing the new data ... that is, I call `RequestContext.create(proxy)`, and only call `RequestContext.fire()` when changes are complete. I don't want to persist a new entity to the server until the user saves their changes. So I'm confused about your suggestion - please explain how this would work.

Comment: In my code I leave client ids null until they are persisted.  I'd update the local ids after the call to fire.  I think if you try to use an id before the object is actually persisted you'll end up with a reference to an object that doesn't exist.